# javascript custom actions on function key press

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a program with a few text boxes and some buttons and calling javascript functions on click event of these buttons. Further I want function keys (F2, F4 etc.) to allow user to call those javascript functions. Following code is running fine and calling correct functions, but problem is that when I press keys with same keycode (q = 113, r = 114, s = 115, t = 116, u = 117, v = 118), these functions execute.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Function Keys Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
    .btn{
        min-width: 200px;
    }
    </style>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

     if(document.addEventListener){ //code for Moz
       document.addEventListener("keydown",keyCapt,false); 
       document.addEventListener("keyup",keyCapt,false);
       document.addEventListener("keypress",keyCapt,false);
     }else{
       document.attachEvent("onkeydown",keyCapt); //code for IE
       document.attachEvent("onkeyup",keyCapt); 
       document.attachEvent("onkeypress",keyCapt); 
     }
     function keyCapt(e){
       if(typeof window.event!="undefined"){
        e=window.event;//code for IE
       }
       if(window.event && e.keyCode==113){ F2_Click();event.keyCode = 0; event.returnValue = false;}
       if(window.event && e.keyCode==114){ F3_Click(); event.keyCode = 0;event.returnValue = false;}
       if(window.event && e.keyCode==116) {F5_Click();event.keyCode = 0; event.returnValue = false;}
       if(window.event && e.keyCode==117) {F6_Click();event.keyCode = 0; event.returnValue = false;}
       if(window.event && e.keyCode==118) {F7_Click();event.keyCode = 0; event.returnValue = false;}
       alert(e.keyCode);
    }

    function F2_Click()
    {
        alert("Save Clicked");
        document.getElementById("txtLabNo").focus();
    }

    function F3_Click()
    {
        alert("Print Clicked");
        document.getElementById("txtLabNo").focus();

    }
    function F5_Click()
    {
        alert("F5 Clicked");
        document.getElementById("txtLabNo").focus();
    }
    function F6_Click()
    {
        alert("F6 Clicked");
        document.getElementById("txtLabNo").focus();
    }
    function F7_Click()
    {
        alert("Save & Print Clicked");
        document.getElementById("txtLabNo").focus();
    }

    </script>

</head>
<body onload="document.getElementById('txtLabNo').focus();">
    <form id="form1">
        <div>
            <table style="width: 900PX; border: solid thin black;">
                <colgroup>
                    <col style="width: 150px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;" />
                    <col style="width: 150px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;" />
                    <col style="width: 350px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;" />
                    <col style="width: 150px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;" />
                </colgroup>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Lab No.</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" tabindex="1" id="txtLabNo" /></td>
                    <td rowspan="5">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td rowspan="5">
                        <input class="btn" type="button" value="Save (F2)" tabindex="10" onclick="F2_Click();" /><br />
                        <input class="btn" type="button" value="Print (F3)" tabindex="11" onclick="F3_Click();" /><br />
                        <input class="btn" type="button" value="Button 5 (F5)" tabindex="12" onclick="F5_Click();" /><br />
                        <input class="btn" type="button" value="Button 6 (F6)" tabindex="13" onclick="F6_Click();" /><br />
                        <input class="btn" type="button" value="Save & Print (F7)" tabindex="14" onclick="F7_Click();" /><br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Patient Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" tabindex="2" id="txtName" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Age</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtAge" tabindex="3" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Test</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtTest" tabindex="4" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Result</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtResult" tabindex="5" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do  using library which is [shortcut.js](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/55765722/delivred/abdennour/lib/js/shortcut.js)

Live Demo : 
[Abdennour JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/XvNGc/55/)

```
   shortcut.add("F2", function() {
    $('span').html("F2 أحسنت. لقد ضغطت على حرفي  C");
        });
    shortcut.add("F3", function() {
    $('span').html("أحسنت. لقد ضغطت على حرفي F3V");
        });

    });
```

Comment: Excellent, Thanks. Though shortcut.js link appears to be broken. I downloaded this from http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/ and program is working perfect.